# AWS Lambda - How do I convert my code to work in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm struggling to get a Lambda function working.  I have a python script to access twitter API, pull information, and export that information into an excel sheet.  I'm trying to transfer python script over to AWS/Lambda, and I'm having a lot of trouble.

What I've done so far:  Created AWS account, setup S3 to have a bucket, and poked around trying to get things to work.

I think the main area I'm struggling is how to go from a python script that I'm executing via local CLI and transforming that code into lambda-capable code.  I'm not sure I understand how the `lambda_handler` function works, what the `event` or `context` arguments actually mean (despite watching a half dozen different tutorial videos), or how to integrate my existing functions into Lambda in the context of the `lambda_handler`, and I'm just very confused and hoping someone might be able to help me get some clarity!

Code that I'm using to pull twitter data (just a sample):

```
import time
import datetime 
import keys
import pandas as pd
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import pymysql


def lambda_handler(event, context):

def oauth_authenticate():
    twitter_oauth = Twython(keys.APP_KEY, keys.APP_SECRET, oauth_version=2)
    ACCESS_TOKEN = twitter_oauth.obtain_access_token()
    twitter = Twython(keys.APP_KEY, access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN)
    return twitter

def get_username():
    """
   Prompts for the screen name of targetted account
    """
    username = input("Enter the Twitter screenname you'd like information on.  Do not include '@':")
    return username

def get_user_followers(username):
    """
    Returns data on all accounts following the targetted user.
    WARNING: The number of followers can be huge, and the data isn't very valuable
    """
    #username = get_username()
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
   twitter = oauth_authenticate()
    datestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    target = twitter.lookup_user(screen_name = username)
    for y in target:
       target_id = y['id_str']
    next_cursor = -1
    index = 0
    followersdata = {}
    while next_cursor:
        try:
            get_followers = twitter.get_followers_list(screen_name = username,
                                                       count = 200,
                                                       cursor = next_cursor)
            for x in get_followers['users']:
                followersdata[index] = {}
                followersdata[index]['screen_name'] = x['screen_name']
                followersdata[index]['id_str'] = x['id_str']
                followersdata[index]['name'] = x['name']
                followersdata[index]['description'] = x['description']
                followersdata[index]['date_checked'] = datestamp
                followersdata[index]['targeted_account_id'] = target_id
                index = index + 1
                next_cursor = get_followers["next_cursor"]
        except TwythonError as e:
            print(e)
            remainder = (float(twitter.get_lastfunction_header(header = 'x-rate-limit-reset')) \
                         - time.time())+1
            print("Rate limit exceeded.  Waiting for:", remainder/60, "minutes")
            print("Current Time is:", time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))
            del twitter
            time.sleep(remainder)
            twitter = oauth_authenticate()
            continue
    followersDF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(followersdata, orient = "index")
    followersDF.to_excel("%s-%s-follower list.xlsx" % (username, datestamp),
                         index = False, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Sounds like [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) might be a solution for you here. I've used it to deploy numerous websites; it's a pretty incredible project.

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy a website though.  Would zappa still be useful?  is it easy to use?

Comment: Lambda functions have to be triggered by an event. That can be an object being uploaded to S3, a timer expiring, an update to a DynamoDB, an API call made via API Gateway, and so on. How do you intend for your Lambda function to be triggered to execute? That will dictate everything about the context and the event.

Comment: After doing some research, what I would *like* to be able to do is use API Gateway to pass a twitter handle (such as @usolympic) and then use that twitter handle to 1) Get all the twitter accounts the 'target' follows, all the twitter accounts that follow the 'target', and all timeline tweets (up to API limit) for the 'target' user.  I'm trying to learn how to use the API gateway stuff now.  I bought into the AWS marketing about using lambda being "easy", and am quickly learning that the AWS marketing team are lying liars who lie.

Comment: I've never used Zappa for anything other than deploying websites, but yes according to the project documentation you can use it to deploy practically any function. The reason you can even use Zappa/Lambda to deploy websites at all is that WSGI web apps can be completely functionalized. Spend half an hour or so looking through the docs and I think you'll get there. It's really not as complicated as it seems at first blush.